# Merge multiple bower.json dependencies in automated way

Tags: javascript, build, dependencies, gulp, bower

I've got a complex architectural problem with `bower`. I'm building an online platform where user create pages using dynamic widgets which contain JS-code. Those widget have predefined format, description, icons etc., they will packaged into archive (like apk's, war's, jar's, ear's but with front-end code). Users will be able to dynamically add widgets when website is already deployed.

We're using `bower` and the problem is the following: widgets should also be able to specify their `bower` dependencies.

Simplified directory layout is the following:

- bower.json
- gulpfile.js (used for website building)
- bower_components # our own deps + deps from all the widgets
- widgets

  - widget1 # any name is possible here
  - widget2
  - widget-random
  - another-widget # for each of the widgets above the layout is the same

    - bower.json (or simplified version like dependencies.json which contains only dependencies list).
    - many other files

After widget is uploaded bower.json should be merged with all the deps from other widgets, `gulp build` will run and rebuild the whole thing.

How do I merge all the bower.json's into a single one? Especially when there is the same dependency twice e.g. one widget depends on  `"jquery": "<=2.1.0"` and another widget depends on `"jquery": "^2.1.0"`. They are both compatible but what string do I write in bower.json? If I write both bower uses only the second and will install the latest jquery - `2.1.1` which is already not compatible with the first widget. And that's a simpler use case.

We can actually assume that there will be not every possible semver spec variation, like `<=` for example. I can also force widget-writers use my own dependency specification but I can't think how to design it.

Any help is appreciated!

Other approached for widget dependency solution are accepted but note: they *cannot* have they're own versions of libs because in runtime multiple widgets are loaded. I can't have two jqueries at once, for example, just because two widgets use specs like in the example above.

UPD: I know about RequireJS and I'm actually using it. But, first, I need to download the dependency itself so I could use it with RequreJS later on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was the following:

each widget itself is a bower package with it's bower.json; The project's bower.json is renamed to bower-base.json and bower.json is generated from bower-base.json with all the widgets added to dependencies property. Then bower automatically handles widget's dependencies.

Comment: I am new to bower. Could you please explain in detail probably with an example so that we can benefit. Thanks!

Comment: The solution is that each widget is a bower package itself. The main project's bower.json has a dependency on each widget.

Comment: is it possible that your main project selects widgets dynamically e.g. including widget1, widget2 and not widget3 without modifying bower.json everytime

Comment: you can write some script which would update bower.json for you, I don't have a ready solution for that

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason this has to be done with bower? Bower isn't really intended for runtime dependencies. For that you want to use something like [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/).

Comment: Oh, well, I already use RequireJS! But how do I download the dependency itself first so I could use it with RequireJS?

Comment: Oh, I see what you're saying. How about this: What if you create a bower.json (and bower_components directory) file for each widget (and place it in the subdirectory with said widget) and then put a task in your main bower.json file to run bower install in those directories?

Comment: As I explained in the question it's not quite possible - if two widgets depend on jQuery I'll end-up loading two jqueries at once. This is obviously a problem.